# Provide values to the ctx.vars variables in the Painless file by extracting them from the YAML file

Tags: elasticsearch-painless

```
I have a .painless file as mentioned below. As of now, the ctx.vars.var1 have hardcoded values to it in my original file, which now need to be retrieved from a YAML file. All these files are in same project, so relative path will not be an issue. 

if(ctx.metadata.Env == 'dev' || ctx.metadata.Env == 'qa' {
    ctx.vars.var1 = 'get this value from a YAML file';
    ctx.vars.var2 = 'get this value from a YAML file';
}
```

An example of YAML file and its content as below. The file name can be SomeFile.yaml, which resides in the same solution.

- name: Key1
  value: Value1
- name: Key2
  value: Value2

I was reading this blog: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting-using.html

Well, I read few more blogs and most of them have hardcoded values as part of Params written down after the script. What I really want to understand is that, is it really possible to work it out the way I expect or its by design that hard code values is the only option at this point of time.

Any help will be much appreciated, as I need to incorporate in my project. Many thanks.